# How to redirect from a CatchAll method without being re-catched in Python/Flask

Tags: python, ajax, routes, flask

I'm building an Web site using Python and Flask and I want the website to run the same way as GrooveShark and Twitter do : having a masterPage with a $.ajax call that append the content of another .html file into a  of the masterPage.

For the moment, my masterPage contains a $.ajax that calls my WebServer passing the current `window.location.href`

I would like to know how to catch all Url in a Python/Flask WebServer and then, on certain condition, redirect without begin recatched by the method !

E.g.
    Based on http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/57/

```
@app.route('/', defaults={'p_path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:p_path>')
def CatchAll(p_path):
    if(p_path.startswith("page/")):
        #if (route exist...I don't know yet how to do this part...):
            #Call the method routed to the /Page/ route
            #  Without being re-catched by the CatchAll method
    elif (p_path.startswith("api/")):
        #Run a method on my API that will call my controller > DAL > Database
        #  Without being re-catched by the CatchAll method
    else:
        #I render my masterpage
        return render_template("masterPage.html")
```

So if the website is loaded for the first time in the browser, it will load the MasterPage, which contains the ajax call that will recall the WebServer passing a URL like "/Page/Contact" which will render the html which I will append in my `<div>`

Do you have any idea of how doing this ?

It's my first draft so feel free to give me comments (optimization, best pratice, performance) because I'm new to Python/Flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need catch all requests for your case.
You can set main page access by `GET` request and ajax by `POST`, for example with next decorator:

```
class AjaxApp(Flask or Blueprint):

    def ajax_route(self, rule, **options):
        def decorator(f):
            @functools.wraps(f)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                return render_template("masterPage.html")

            endpoint = options.pop('endpoint', None)
            methods = options.pop('methods', ['GET', 'POST'])
            self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, wrapper, methods=methods, **options)
            return wrapper
        return decorator
```

You also can just check `X-Requested-With` header if do not want restrict access for each methods:

```
class AjaxApp(Flask or Blueprint):

    def ajax_route(self, rule, **options):
        def decorator(f):
            @functools.wraps(f)
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                if request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                return render_template("masterPage.html")

            endpoint = options.pop('endpoint', None)
            self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, wrapper, **options)
            return wrapper
        return decorator
```

This methods very implicit and you should use just `ajax_route` for your special ajax pages, but it increase complexity and probably better use Pluggable Views http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/views/.

If you want group logic by api, pages and other you can look at blueprints http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/:

```
class AjaxBlueprint(Blueprint):
    def route(self, rule, **options):
        # one of examples

ajax = AjaxBlueprint('ajax', __name__)

@ajax.route('/main.html')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')

app.register_blueprint(ajax)
```

and override `route` with one of examples method for blueprint. So ajax bluprint in this case will have custom logic, others blueprint will have independent.

Comment: Do you have any example of who could I use the ajax_route decorator in a blueprint context ?

Comment: It the same to last code example (fixed misprint), but just replace `route` to `ajax_route` in `AjaxBlueprint`. To understand difference with standard `route` compare it with `app` or `blueprint` implementation: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L986 and https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/blueprints.py#L155. Actually it is not clear what you want see as example, so can you ask more concrete questions if you want clarify something?

Comment: Never mind, I didn't saw your example at the end of your answer. But I'm not sure to understand. Do I need to use `route` or `ajax_route` in the `AjaxBlueprint` class ? And do I need to use `route` or `ajax_route` with the `@` above my method ? Also, I'm getting an error message : `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'expandtabs'` inside `MyApplication > textwrap.py > @wrap > w.wrap(text) > text = self._munge_whitespace(text) > text = text.expandtabs()`

Comment: Yes you should use `route` or `route_ajax` to subscribe your routes (urls to method dispatchers), but if you already do not know this routes or it more difficult you can use more generic approach with `route('/<path:path>')` and custom logic inside like in your question example. However better split as possible main routes to not reimplement existing route system.

`@` is decorator usage definition, you can use `add_url_rule` or directly work with `Flask.url_map` instead `route`. However `route` better use as decorator with `@`.

You should use `functools.wraps` for function wrapping (upd).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the modification of your example.Is it normal that in your example you aren't doing anything with the `wrapper()` method ?